# OpenGL Google maps style 2D camera / zoom to mouse cursor

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, geometry, zooming

I am trying to implement a 2D camera in OpenGL that behaves like the Google maps camera. Specifically the "zoom to mouse point" functionality.

So far I have been able to implement pan and zoom OK - but only if the zoom is locked to the center of the window/widget. If I try to zoom on the mouse location the view seems to "jump" and after the zoom level increases the item I zoomed in on is no longer under the mouse cursor.

My camera class is below - quite a lot of code but I couldn't make it any smaller sorry!

I call `Apply()` on the start of each frame, and I call `SetX/YPos` when the scene is panned, finally I call `SetScale` with the previous scale `+/- 0.1f` with the mouse position when the mouse wheel is scrolled.

---

**camera.h**

```
class Camera
{
public:
    Camera();

    void Apply();

    void SetXPos(float xpos);
    void SetYPos(float ypos);
    void SetScale(float scaleFactor, float mx, float my);

    float XPos() const { return m_XPos; }
    float YPos() const { return m_YPos; }
    float Scale() const { return m_ScaleFactor; }

    void SetWindowSize(int w, int h);
    void DrawTestItems();

private:
    void init_matrix();

    float m_XPos;
    float m_YPos;

    float m_ScaleFactor;

    float m_Width;
    float m_Height;

    float m_ZoomX;
    float m_ZoomY;
};
```

---

**camera.cpp**

```
Camera::Camera()
    : m_XPos(0.0f),
      m_YPos(0.0f),
      m_ScaleFactor(1.0f),
      m_ZoomX(0.0f),
      m_ZoomY(0.0f),
      m_Width(0.0f),
      m_Height(0.0f)
{

}

// Called when window is created and when window is resized
void Camera::SetWindowSize(int w, int h)
{
    m_Width = (float)w;
    m_Height = (float)h;
}

void Camera::init_matrix()
{
    glViewport(0, 0, m_Width, m_Height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    float new_W = m_Width * m_ScaleFactor;
    float new_H = m_Height * m_ScaleFactor;

    // Point to zoom on
    float new_x = m_ZoomX;
    float new_y = m_ZoomY;

    glOrtho( -new_W/2+new_x,
              new_W/2+new_x,
              new_H/2+new_y,
              -new_H/2+new_y,
             -1,1);


    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void Camera::Apply()
{
    // Zoom
    init_matrix();

    // Pan
    glTranslatef( m_XPos, m_YPos, 1.0f );

    DrawTestItems();
}

void Camera::SetXPos(float xpos)
{
    m_XPos = xpos;
}

void Camera::SetYPos(float ypos)
{
    m_YPos = ypos;
}

// mx,my = window coords of mouse pos when wheel was scrolled
// scale factor goes up or down by 0.1f
void Camera::SetScale(float scaleFactor, float mx, float my)
{

    m_ZoomX = (float)mx;
    m_ZoomY = (float)my;

    m_ScaleFactor = scaleFactor;

}

void Camera::DrawTestItems()
{

}
```

Update: I seem to have noticed 2 issues:

1. The mouse position in SetScale is incorrect - I don't know why.
2. No matter what I try glOrtho causes the centre of the screen to be the zoom point,I confirmed this setting the zoom point manually/hard coding it. In Google maps the screen won't "stick" to the centre like this.

Update again:

I'm also using Qt if this makes any difference, I just have a basic QGLWidget and I am using the mouse wheel event to perform the zoom. I take the delta of the wheel event and then either add or subtract 0.1f to the scale passing in the mouse position from the wheel event.

Comment: How do the "mouse zoom in/out" with mouse wheel?

Comment: In the mouse wheel call back (from Qt) I simply call m_Camera.SetScale( m_Camera.Scale() + 0.1f, mouseWheelEvent->x(), mouseWheelEvent->y() ); (or I use - 0.1f depending on the wheel direction/delta)

Comment: QWheelEvent docs here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwheelevent.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Get the world-space coordinates of the mouse cursor using the current zoom factor and model/proj/view matrices.
2. Adjust zoom factor
3. Get the world-space mouse coordinates again using the new zoom factor
4. Shift the camera position by the difference in world-space mouse coordinates
5. Redraw scene using new camera position and zoom factor

Something like this (in the `wheel()` callback):

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>


glm::dvec3 Unproject( const glm::dvec3& win )
{
    glm::ivec4 view;
    glm::dmat4 proj, model;
    glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, &model[0][0] );
    glGetDoublev( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, &proj[0][0] );
    glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, &view[0] );

    glm::dvec3 world = glm::unProject( win, model, proj, view );
    return world;
}

// unprojects the given window point
// and finds the ray intersection with the Z=0 plane
glm::dvec2 PlaneUnproject( const glm::dvec2& win )
{
    glm::dvec3 world1 = Unproject( glm::dvec3( win, 0.01 ) );
    glm::dvec3 world2 = Unproject( glm::dvec3( win, 0.99 ) );

    // u is a value such that:
    // 0 = world1.z + u * ( world2.z - world1.z )
    double u = -world1.z / ( world2.z - world1.z );
    // clamp u to reasonable values
    if( u < 0 ) u = 0;
    if( u > 1 ) u = 1;

    return glm::dvec2( world1 + u * ( world2 - world1 ) );
}

// pixels per unit
const double ppu = 1.0;

glm::dvec2 center( 0 );
double scale = 1.0;
void ApplyCamera()
{
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    const double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH ) / ppu;
    const double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) / ppu;
    glOrtho( -w/2, w/2, -h/2, h/2, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glScaled( scale, scale, 1.0 );
    glTranslated( -center[0], -center[1], 0 );
}

glm::dvec2 mPos;

glm::dvec2 centerStart( 0 );
int btn = -1;

void mouse( int button, int state, int x, int y )
{
    ApplyCamera();

    y = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) - y;
    mPos = glm::ivec2( x, y );

    btn = button;
    if( GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON == btn && GLUT_DOWN == state )
    {
        centerStart = PlaneUnproject( glm::dvec2( x, y ) );
    }
    if( GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON == btn && GLUT_UP == state )
    {
        btn = -1;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void motion( int x, int y )
{
    y = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) - y;
    mPos = glm::ivec2( x, y );

    if( GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON == btn )
    {
        ApplyCamera();
        glm::dvec2 cur = PlaneUnproject( glm::dvec2( x, y ) );
        center += ( centerStart - cur );
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void passiveMotion( int x, int y )
{
    y = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) - y;
    mPos = glm::ivec2( x, y );
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void wheel( int wheel, int direction, int x, int y )
{
    y = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) - y;
    mPos = glm::ivec2( x, y );

    ApplyCamera();
    glm::dvec2 beforeZoom = PlaneUnproject( glm::dvec2( x, y ) );

    const double scaleFactor = 0.90;
    if( direction == -1 )   scale *= scaleFactor;
    if( direction ==  1 )   scale /= scaleFactor;

    ApplyCamera();
    glm::dvec2 afterZoom = PlaneUnproject( glm::dvec2( x, y ) );

    center += ( beforeZoom - afterZoom );

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 1 );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    ApplyCamera();

    glm::dvec2 cur = PlaneUnproject( mPos );
    cout << cur.x << " " << cur.y << " " << scale << endl;

    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef( 50, 50, 1 );
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glColor3ub( 255, 255, 255 );
    glVertex2i( -1, -1 );
    glVertex2i(  1, -1 );
    glVertex2i(  1,  1 );
    glVertex2i( -1,  1 );
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 600, 600 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );

    glutMouseFunc( mouse );
    glutMotionFunc( motion );
    glutMouseWheelFunc( wheel );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutPassiveMotionFunc( passiveMotion );

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem correct. I'm using 1 unit = 1 pixel so I change the test rect to be 100 instead of 1 and ppu to be 1 rather than 80. I found that if you pan so the top left of the rect is in the top left of the window, then zoom in with the mouse on the bottom right of the rect, then the rect/pan location starts to move up. And the mouse position is no longer on the bottom right of the rect?

Comment: I *think* that's just minor initial targeting inaccuracies being exaggerated by large (~100-200) scale factors.  You can see something similar on Google Maps by zooming all the way out, targeting [the Four Corners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Corners), and zooming in.

Comment: It seems to be off by about 20 units though, I would have figured the error of margin would only be 0.5-1?

Comment: Another thought - the scale never goes about 10x so its far from 100-200 scale factor..

Comment: @paulm: Edited the code to print the mouse position.  When the cursor is on exactly (50, -50) I can zoom in without any drift.

Comment: Ah yes - wheel event wasn't working in my version of glut so I changed it to use the right mouse button and introduced a bug :). Could  you explain what glm:swizzel is doing? Is PlaneUnproject the same as gluUnProject?

Comment: [`swizzle` lets you rearrange/slice/expand vector components.](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Data_Type_%28GLSL%29#Swizzling)  In this case I'm just using it to slice off the Z component, going from a `dvec3` to a `dvec2`.  `Unproject()` corresponds to `gluUnProject()`.  `PlaneUnproject()` lets you figure out where (in world coordinates) a ray shot "into" the screen intersects an imaginary Z=0 plane.  I did it that way so the same pan/zoom system would be usable in a 3D environment too.

Comment: Thanks, one more question.. is the value of glm::dvec2 center always without scale, i.e this is always the pan location without scale? If it has scale it safe just to divide it by scale to get the pan location?

Comment: Yep, `center` is unscaled.

Comment: I have another query, hopefully you might know. If center is scaled and have scroll bars on the widget displaying the viewport, then how can I know what the max value of the scroll bar should be if the rect is say 800x200 and the viewport is 400x400? When the scale is used it seems to go wrong.

Comment: This adds a displacement in y for me. Is that supposed to happen? i.e., when I zoom, the zoom does not happen in the point I want, but the map slowly drifts in y

Comment: it should end up that what you see under the mouse is always the same pixel/point

Comment: Absolutely perfect thanks