# 'swizzle' is not a member of 'glm'

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am using the following code to implement the "zoom to mouse point" functionality in opengl in c++. Most of the code is from 
[OpenGL Google maps style 2D camera / zoom to mouse cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561724/opengl-google-maps-style-2d-camera-zoom-to-mouse-cursor) but I had to change some include statements because of changes in the GLM (http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html) codebase.

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define GLM_SWIZZLE_XYZW 
#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS

#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "glm/detail/setup.hpp"
#include "glm/detail/_swizzle.hpp"
#include "glm/detail/_swizzle_func.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp"
glm::dvec3 Unproject( const glm::dvec3& win )
{
glm::ivec4 view;
glm::dmat4 proj, model;
glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, glm::value_ptr( model ) );
glGetDoublev( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, glm::value_ptr( proj ) );
glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, glm::value_ptr( view ) );
glm::dvec3 world = glm::unProject( win, model, proj, view );
return world;
}
// unprojects the given window point
// and finds the ray intersection with the Z=0 plane
glm::dvec2 PlaneUnproject( const glm::dvec2& win )
{
glm::dvec3 world1 = Unproject( glm::dvec3( win, 0.01 ) );
glm::dvec3 world2 = Unproject( glm::dvec3( win, 0.99 ) );
// u is a value such that:
// 0 = world1.z + u * ( world2.z - world1.z )
double u = -world1.z / ( world2.z - world1.z );
// clamp u to reasonable values
if( u < 0 ) u = 0;
if( u > 1 ) u = 1;
return glm::swizzle< glm::X, glm::Y >( world1 + u * ( world2 - world1 ) );
}
// pixels per unit
const double ppu = 80.0;
glm::dvec2 center( 0 );
double scale = 1.0;
void ApplyCamera()
{
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
const double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH ) / ppu;
const double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) / ppu;
glOrtho( -w/2, w/2, -h/2, h/2, -1, 1 );
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();
glScaled( scale, scale, 1.0 );
glTranslated( -center[0], -center[1], 0 );
}
glm::dvec2 centerStart( 0 );
int btn = -1;
void mouse( int button, int state, int x, int y )
{
ApplyCamera();
y = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) - y;
btn = button;
if( GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON == btn && GLUT_DOWN == state )
{
centerStart = PlaneUnproject( glm::dvec2( x, y ) );
}
if( GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON == btn && GLUT_UP == state )
{
btn = -1;
}
glutPostRedisplay();
}
void motion( int x, int y )
{
y = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) - y;
if( GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON == btn )
{
ApplyCamera();
glm::dvec2 cur = PlaneUnproject( glm::dvec2( x, y ) );
center += ( centerStart - cur );
}
glutPostRedisplay();
}
void wheel( int wheel, int direction, int x, int y )
{
y = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) - y;
ApplyCamera();
glm::dvec2 beforeZoom = PlaneUnproject( glm::dvec2( x, y ) );
const double scaleFactor = 0.90;
if( direction == -1 ) scale *= scaleFactor;
if( direction == 1 ) scale /= scaleFactor;
ApplyCamera();
glm::dvec2 afterZoom = PlaneUnproject( glm::dvec2( x, y ) );
center += ( beforeZoom - afterZoom );
glutPostRedisplay();
}
void display()
{
glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 1 );
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
ApplyCamera();
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
glVertex2i( -1, -1 );
glVertex2i( 1, -1 );
glVertex2i( 1, 1 );
glVertex2i( -1, 1 );
glEnd();
glutSwapBuffers();
}
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
glutInit( &argc, argv );
glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE );
glutInitWindowSize( 600, 600 );
glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
glutMouseFunc( mouse );
glutMotionFunc( motion );
glutMouseWheelFunc( wheel );
glutDisplayFunc( display );
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

The errors

```
error: 'swizzle' is not a member of 'glm'
error: 'X' is not a member of 'glm'
error: 'Y' is not a member of 'glm'
```

are in line

```
return glm::swizzle< glm::X, glm::Y >( world1 + u * ( world2 - world1 ) );
```

I know that `glm::swizzle` is obviously wrong but `glm::detail::_swizzle` requires 8 parameters compared to 2 earlier by `glm::swizzle`. What would be the new parameters be? Also, I don't know how to correct `glm::X` and `glm::Y`. Can someone please help?

Comment: Why are you swizzling anything at all? You want the order of the components to be XYZW juding by `#define GLM_SWIZZLE_XYZW`. That is already the order produced when you construct your vectors. Swizzles would only be necessary if you wanted something unusual like to store ZW (instead of XY) in your `dvec2`. *By the way, your code is ridiculously hard to read without any indentation or whitespace between functions - is that a paste error?*

Answer (score 4):

Actually you don't need swizzling at all in this case since there's a `dvec2` constructor that can slice off the z coordinate for you.

Change the last line of `PlaneUnproject()` from this:

```
return glm::swizzle< glm::X, glm::Y >( world1 + u * ( world2 - world1 ) );
```

to this:

```
return glm::dvec2( world1 + u * ( world2 - world1 ) );
```

I updated the complete code in my [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21614272/44729).

---

Though if you *really* want to swizzle:

Pare down your `#include`s:

```
#define GLM_SWIZZLE
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
```

And change the last line of `PlaneUnproject()` from this:

```
return glm::swizzle< glm::X, glm::Y >( world1 + u * ( world2 - world1 ) );
```

to this:

```
return ( world1 + u * ( world2 - world1 ) ).xy();
```

Answer (score 1):

In newer version of glm if you want swizzle operator you need to define GLM_FORCE_SWIZZLE before including glm. GLM_SWIZZLE is deprecated.

```
#define GLM_FORCE_SWIZZLE
#include "glm/glm.hpp"
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
return world1.yx();
```

And on some compiler you can also do it like this:

```
return world1.yx;
```

Warning: Just be aware that there is a huge performance impact if you enable it.
On Visual Studio 2013 I measure around x150 speed difference in runtime matrix multiplication.

With swizzle operations:   450 000 multiplications per second.

Without swizzle operations: 65 000 000 multiplications per second.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's pretty straightforward. Under the glm namespace there's no member known as 'swizzle'. Please check these two points :-

1. Just check if there is a nested namespace and refer it accordingly like `glm::detail::swizzle`
2. Else please check if the member name is `swizzle` or `_swizzle`.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Nirmal but as I mentioned in the last part of my question, I tried that already but haven't been able to figure out what would be the extra parameters.