# opengl camera zoom to cursor, avoiding > 90deg fov

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3, glm-math

I'm trying to set up a google maps style zoom-to-cursor control for my opengl camera. I'm using a similar method to the one suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561724/opengl-google-maps-style-2d-camera-zoom-to-mouse-cursor). Basically, I  get the position of the cursor, and calculate the width/height of my perspective view at that depth using some trigonometry. I then change the field of view, and calculate how to much I need to translate in order to keep the point under the cursor in the same apparent position on the screen. That part works pretty well.

The issue is that I want to limit the fov to be less than 90 degrees. When it ends up >90, I cut it in half and then translate everything away from the camera so that the resulting scene looks the same as with the larger fov. The equation to find that necessary translation isn't working, which is strange because it comes from pretty simple algebra. I can't find my mistake. Here's the relevant code.

```
void Visual::scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    glm::mat4 modelview = view*model;
    glm::vec4 viewport = { 0.0, 0.0, width, height };

    float winX = cursorPrevX;
    float winY = viewport[3] - cursorPrevY;
    float winZ;

    glReadPixels(winX, winY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ);
    glm::vec3 screenCoords = { winX, winY, winZ };

    glm::vec3 cursorPosition = glm::unProject(screenCoords, modelview, projection, viewport);

    if (isinf(cursorPosition[2]) || isnan(cursorPosition[2])) {
        cursorPosition[2] = 0.0;
    }

    float zoomFactor = 1.1;
    // = zooming in 
    if (yoffset > 0.0)
        zoomFactor = 1/1.1;

    //the width and height of the perspective view, at the depth of the cursor position 
    glm::vec2 fovXY = camera.getFovXY(cursorPosition[2] - zTranslate, width / height);
    camera.setZoomFromFov(fovXY.y * zoomFactor, cursorPosition[2] - zTranslate);

    //don't want fov to be greater than 90, so cut it in half and move the world farther away from the camera to compensate
    //not working...
    if (camera.Zoom > 90.0 && zTranslate*2 > MAX_DEPTH) {
        float prevZoom = camera.Zoom;
        camera.Zoom *= .5;

        //need increased distance between camera and world origin, so that view does not appear to change when fov is reduced
        zTranslate = cursorPosition[2] - tan(glm::radians(prevZoom)) / tan(glm::radians(camera.Zoom) * (cursorPosition[2] - zTranslate));
    }
    else if (camera.Zoom > 90.0) {
        camera.Zoom = 90.0;
    }

    glm::vec2 newFovXY = camera.getFovXY(cursorPosition[2] - zTranslate, width / height);

    //translate so that position under the cursor does not appear to move.
    xTranslate += (newFovXY.x - fovXY.x) * (winX / width - .5);
    yTranslate += (newFovXY.y - fovXY.y) * (winY / height - .5);

    updateView = true;
}
```

The definition of my view matrix. Called ever iteration of the main loop.

```
void Visual::setView() {
    view = glm::mat4();

    view = glm::translate(view, { xTranslate,yTranslate,zTranslate });

    view = glm::rotate(view, glm::radians(camera.inclination), glm::vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f));
    view = glm::rotate(view, glm::radians(camera.azimuth), glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f));

    camera.Right = glm::column(view, 0).xyz();
    camera.Up = glm::column(view, 1).xyz();
    camera.Front = -glm::column(view, 2).xyz(); // minus because OpenGL camera looks towards negative Z.
    camera.Position = glm::column(view, 3).xyz();

    updateView = false;
}
```

Field of view helper functions.

```
glm::vec2 getFovXY(float depth, float aspectRatio) {
    float fovY = tan(glm::radians(Zoom / 2)) * depth;
    float fovX = fovY * aspectRatio;

    return glm::vec2{ 2*fovX , 2*fovY };
}

//you have a desired fov, and you want to set the zoom to achieve that.
//factor of 1/2 inside the atan because we actually need the half-fov. Keep full-fov as input for consistency 
void setZoomFromFov(float fovY, float depth) {
    Zoom = glm::degrees(2 * atan(fovY / (2 * depth)));
}
```

The equations I'm using can be found from the diagram [here](http://wiki.panotools.org/Field_of_View). Since I want to have the same field of view dimensions before and after the angle is changed, I start with

```
fovY = tan(theta1) * d1 = tan(theta2) * d2
d2 = (tan(theta1) / tan(theta2)) * d1

d1 = distance between camera and cursor position, before fov change = cursorPosition[2] - zTranslate
d2 = distance after
theta1 = fov angle before
theta2 = fov angle after = theta1 * .5
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: If you want to do anything like the 3D google-maps version then your current approach won't bring you far. Instead define `float zoom` that changes linearily, clamped, and then define camera position, fov and orientation as functions of `zoom`.

Comment: I think I might have created a bit of confusion with a badly named variable. My camera.Zoom is the fov parameter that I plug into glm::perspective to generate my projection matrix. But I don't think it makes sense to change zoom linearly. If you do that,the apparent zoom is extremely abrupt at low fov angle, and it barely changes at all in high fov angle. Much better to chage as a fraction of the current zoom level, so it appears smooth for the whole scale. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: This strikes me as far more complicated than necessary. My suggestion would be to use the camera position alone for map-type zoom. If you want to do a street level transition, it may be appropriate to apply additional orientation and FOV transformations as the camera approaches maximum zoom.